# Android keyboard and play store not working

Tags: google-play-store, keyboard, force-close

Android Keyboard and Google Play Store app are not working on my Jelly Bean device. There is a message popping up repeatedly telling me that android keyboard has stopped.

What can I do to get out of that loop, and have a usable device again?

Comment: What you are describing is a classical force-close-loop. I've added the corresponding tag to your question; please check with the [force-close tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/force-close/info) for first aid and report back if you were able to solve your issue with those. The [most frequented questions with this tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force-close?sort=frequent) might prove helpful as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can fix Android Force Close Error by going through the solutions given in the presentation tutorial. Find it here http://www.slideshare.net/StenaGlass/android-force-close-error-fix

I am hopeful that you will resolve your problem as I have already fixed it!

Wish you best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to provide an answer. Your effort will go waste if the link you provide becomes unreachable. Hence, it would be better if you can provide a reasonable (with the reason in mind) gist. :)